# Building docker image for karma testing headlessChrome

Tags: angular, docker, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

I am modifying my CI/CD setup for testing and deploying an Angular application, and moving to docker containers.

My issue is that the chrome headless is failing. I have an idea that I have to add `--No-Sandbox` but adding that to
`ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless` doesn't work.

> 09:42:56  12 12 2022 09:42:56.146:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless
> 09:42:56    Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
> 09:42:56  [1212/084248.101294:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
> 09:42:56  [1212/084248.101482:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
> 09:42:56  [1212/084248.105577:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /tmp/Crashpad/attachments/dcd79a17-adad-4f9f-ac32-59481a449721: No such file or directory (2)

`ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless`

### [Dockerfile](https://github.com/JoSSte/npm-docker-build-slave/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```ini
... 
# install chrome headless

RUN npm install -g -D karma-chrome-launcher puppeteer
RUN apt-get install -qy libappindicator1 fonts-liberation libgbm1 libgtk-4-1 libxkbcommon0 xdg-utils
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb

...
```

### karma.conf.js

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'), //TODO add Firefox, edge
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'build',
      outputFile: 'testreport.xml',
      useBrowserName: false
    }
  });
};
```

### Edit: connecting to the docker image

I connected to the container and ran `google-chrome --no-sandbox --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 https://www.chromestatus.com`

That resulted in this:

> `root@4435092f0e80:/# google-chrome --no-sandbox --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 https://www.chromestatus.com
> [1212/161152.688008:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
> [1212/161152.688146:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory

> `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/a6a63639-ac31-407e-bb00-76266141f121 [1212/161152.694180:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable. [1212/161152.713499:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(380)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.`

> `root@4435092f0e80:/# google-chrome --no-sandbox --headless --disable-gpu https://www.chromestatus.com   [1212/161401.855472:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory   [1212/161401.855621:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory   [1212/161401.858246:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.   [1212/161401.877705:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(380)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.`

and running ng test:

$ ng test
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
12 12 2022 17:27:52.479:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
12 12 2022 17:27:52.491:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.1 server started at http://localhost:9876/
12 12 2022 17:27:52.492:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
12 12 2022 17:27:52.496:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
12 12 2022 17:27:52.549:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[1212/162752.544002:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1212/162752.544048:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

12 12 2022 17:27:52.549:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout:
12 12 2022 17:27:52.550:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[1212/162752.544002:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1212/162752.544048:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

12 12 2022 17:27:52.554:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
12 12 2022 17:27:52.609:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[1212/162752.602460:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1212/162752.602523:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

12 12 2022 17:27:52.610:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout:
12 12 2022 17:27:52.610:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [492:492:0100/000000.559793:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(661)] write: Broken pipe (32)
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[1212/162752.602460:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1212/162752.602523:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

12 12 2022 17:27:52.612:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
12 12 2022 17:27:52.671:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[1212/162752.666776:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1212/162752.666848:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

12 12 2022 17:27:52.672:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout:
12 12 2022 17:27:52.672:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [508:508:0100/000000.618809:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(661)] write: Broken pipe (32)
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[1212/162752.666776:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1212/162752.666848:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

12 12 2022 17:27:52.674:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add a custom browser config in karma.conf.js:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
      basePath: '',
      frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
      plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
      ],
      client:{
        clearContext: false
      },
      reporters: ['progress'],
      port: 9876,
      colors: true,
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
      autoWatch: true,
      browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
      customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessCI: {
          base: 'ChromeHeadless',
          flags: ['--no-sandbox', 'disable-gpu']
        }
      },
      singleRun: true
    });
  };
```

and then update the npm script in package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-headless": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI",

...
```

So now `ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI` (or `npm run test-headless`) runs with success.